# Android Bring activity to front when we have multiple instances of one activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an Activity say `TaskActivity`. which can have multiple instances running in my app. each `TaskActivity` is viewing a task with a specific id and when something happens on each task I want to bring the related `TaskActiviy` to front and show that.

how can I bring the related activity to front? they are already created but not in the front of the task

some related questions proposed `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` but here I have a single activity type with multiple instances and I want to programmatically decide whether to create a new or bring up an existing activity.

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949898/multiple-activity-instances-and-flag-activity-reorder-to-front/13382280#13382280

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39100966/traverse-between-activities-in-stack/39104837#39104837

Comment: You can't. I've closed this question as duplicate. Please see the linked questions for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you use Fragments(instead of activity). Tag every fragment with a unique name, may be 'task_name'. Write your complete logic of bringing up particular fragment(by using tag name) in Activity.