# How to navigate to a specific activity on the backstack

Tags: android, android-activity

I am working on an Android app in which I want the user to be able to launch multiple sessions i.e. launch the same activity (MainActivity) multiple times and be able to switch between them. I was thinking of a static class which assigns a unique ID on activity creation (e.g. when a user presses a button to create a new session) and for the navigation you need to specify the activity name (in this case all the time MainActivity) plus the unique ID and then the user gets transferred to that particular activity on the back stack (brought to the front).
There could even be another activity (the "tab view") which displays all my activities plus their ID on the back stack and the user could simply click on any of those to bring that particular activity to the front.
I know this must be possible somehow but I was not able to figure out a working approach. I want those different activities to run completely separate from each other.

Hope someone can help me out by pointing me into the good direction. Thanks.

I tried working with intents and extras (adding the activity ID) when launching a duplicate of the current activity but was not able navigate freely between them.

Comment: Please see my answer to this question. It might give you some ideas. Basically having multiple instances of the same `Activity` in the task stack is a bad architecture for Android. You are better off using a single instance of that `Activity` and managing the data shown in the instance in a stack yourself. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39100966/traverse-between-activities-in-stack/39104837#39104837

Comment: Also see my answer to this question to understand how `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` works when trying to navigate to a specific instance of an `Activity` in the task stack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949898/multiple-activity-instances-and-flag-activity-reorder-to-front/13382280#13382280